# Download a file from the second HDD of my server

Tags: php, download

I want to share files which are placed on the second HDD of my server. At this moment I use/adapted the following script:

```
$file_path  = $DLPath."/$file";//$_REQUEST['file'];
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: -1");
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

// set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
if ($is_attachment)
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
else
    header('Content-Disposition: inline;');

// set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
$ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
$content_types = array(
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
    "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
    "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
);
$ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);
```

`$DLPath` is a absolute path (/mnt/disk100).

I believe that the error occures within the "header" call. But I do not know how I can handle this.

Comment: `mnt/disk100` is not absolute. `/mnt/disk100` is

Comment: sorry, this was a copy/paste error...

Comment: is `$file_name` defined? Also, is there any relevant informaton in your error logs?

Comment: yes it is. The script works fine if I download from the main HDD...
In the error logs are no entries.

Comment: You don't appear to ever use `$file_path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a permission error from `Apache2` or `SElinux`.

To bypass this, you can setup a `symlink`:

```
ln -s /mnt/disk100 /path/to/your/www/root/directory/disk100
```

and read the file from this location

This may also be of help: [SElinux tutorial (jumped to section 5.1)](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-0f6390ddacfab39ee973ed8018a32212c2a02199)